# Error while trying to deploy mean stack app to heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack

I'm getting the following error while trying to deploy mean stack application to heroku...

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

```
modules/camelcase
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:        removed 892 packages in 10.113s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 19.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://rocky-coast-36852.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/rocky-coast-36852.git
   142c119..1679a58  master -> master
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Here is my app.js file

```
//importing modules
var express=require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var cors=require('cors');
var path=require('path');

var app=express();

const route=require('./routes/route');

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlistapp');

//on connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected',()=>{

console.log('connected to mongodb @27107');


});
mongoose.connection.on('error',(err)=>{
if(err)
{

console.log('error in database connecton'+err);

}


});

//port number
const port=3000;
// adding middleware-cors
app.use(cors());

//body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//routes
app.use('/api',route);



//testing server
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.send('foobar');
});


app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log('serve started at'+port);

});
```

Are any any other steps to be followed after git push heroku master?

Comment: Hey sorry actually i gave server.js instead of app.js...

Comment: But when i visit the following url https://rocky-coast-36852.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku...it is showing application error....here is my app.js file

Comment: Hey thanks its working fine now, but there is a problem with database now on trying to connect its showing

Comment: serve started at3000
error in database connectonMongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
(node:42332) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: It's because Heroku doesn't host a database for you. You have to get a database from a provider such as [mlab](https://mlab.com/) (it's free for DBs up to 500 MB). After that, you have to change the DB URL in app.js.